# mod_rewrite from specific IP ranges

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

If a user is trying to access www.example.com/local

I want to send him to www.example.com/home if he has from a certain IP address, and www.example.com/work if he is not in that IP range.

What would be the best way to do that using mod_rewrite?

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.\123\.123\.123$
```

Also in the above example, what is the purpose of the backslashes and the $ sign?
I thought a backslash was an escape character, but then I'm not sure why you would be escaping the 1 in the 2nd group of digits

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(more questions in one is usually frowned upon, as I have seen it)

escaping a 1 is just a 1, I think,

$ means the end of the string

and ^ is the start except inside [].

the backslashes are meant to say that we look for a real . and not just any character.

You can test your regexes on your ip address ranges using for example regexr.com